# Copy DataFrame columns with particular labels to new pandas DataFrame under different labels

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, copy

Currently trying to do following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Creating empty data frame with column indexes

```
currentDataToAdd = pd.read_csv('product-export-empty.csv', header=0)
```

Importing Data that needs to be reformated

```
newData = pd.read_csv('ChermsideStock.csv', header=0)
```

Reformating Data into currentDataToAdd (all labels exist in two data frames)

```
currentDataToAdd.loc[:,'sku'] = newData3.loc[:,'Barcode']
currentDataToAdd.loc[:,'name'] = newData3.loc[:,'Description']
currentDataToAdd.loc[:,'tax_name'] = newData3.loc[:,'Sales_Tax']
currentDataToAdd.loc[:,'supply_price'] = newData3.loc[:,'Cost']
currentDataToAdd.loc[:,'retail_price'] = newData3.loc[:,'Sell']
```

The problem is what I'm getting in currentDataToAdd is the data but in wrong columns. Please help. What am I doing wrong?

**newData3**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW5G1.png)

**currentDataToAdd**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx03N.png)

**Result**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'product-export-empty.csv' just has the columns and nothing else, and 'ChermsideStock.csv' has your data and you want to have the two combined. You can that by:

```
df_empty = pd.read_csv('product-export-empty.csv')
df_data = pd.read_csv('ChermsideStock.csv', header=None)
df_data.columns = df_empty.columns
```

Two things to keep in mind:

- better to use lower case variable names with underscores between words
- better use very clear names that allow no ambiquity
- Pandas is very elegant, and things are usually very simple to do syntax wise